# How to handle the multiple result and get the output paramater from a stored procedure in java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, stored-procedures, error-handling

My stored procedure will request is:

- @USER_ID BIGINT,
- @Country_Name VARCHAR(15)= NULL,
- @ZONE BIT= NULL,
- @STATUS BIT= 1,
- @All_Rows INT OUTPUT

And result is:

```
 COUNTRY_ID | CONTRY_NAME | ZONE | STATUS | CACULATE_FIELD |
```

And a output

I call this function is:

```
DECLARE @All_Rows INT; 

usp_GetALLByUser_Id @User_ID = 201, @All_Rows = @All_Rows OUTPUT, SELECT @All_Rows;
```

When I get result in java code:

```
public List<Contry> getAllCommunitiesByUserId(Long userId) {

    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager
            .createStoredProcedureQuery("usp_GetAllCountry);

        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("User_ID", Long.class,  ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("All_Rows", Integer.class,     ParameterMode.OUT);
        // Set input parameter values
       storedProcedure.setParameter("User_ID", userId);
        // Execute the stored procedure
        storedProcedure.execute();
        Object object = storedProcedure.getOutputParameterValue("All_Rows");

        // Get the output parameter value
        List<Object[]> list = storedProcedure.getResultList();


        return null;
}
```

When I run the application, and call this function, this error is:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The index 5 is out of range.
>
> Error preparing registered callable parameter

I hope any one can see this post and help me to resolve for this issue.

Thanks for all.